# Only allowing one instance of a user logged into a website

Tags: php, mysql

At the moment, in my website several people could technically log in using the same username and password at the same time on different machines.

I want to make it so that if someone logs in then it automatically ends any session associated with that user. That way, only one instance of a particular user can be logged in at any one time.

I'm trying to figure out how to implement this. How can someone logging in and creating a new session destroy a specific session on a different machine?

Comment: Just put users IP on login in the database and in a session. If session IP matches the one in the database, it's ok. If not, redirect to a session destroy page.

Comment: By IP, browser, or even OS.

Comment: @icecub There is such a thing as dynamic IPs. This solution of yours completely ignores this.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen I'm not sure how your country works, but I've never seen a dynamic IP change "on the fly". This usually only happens after an x amount of hours of inactivity on the router which causes the ip to be released. I'm not saying my solution is perfect. I'm just saying it's a step into the right direction. Hence the comment and not an answer.

Comment: You keep saying "database" in the question @dlofrodloh but the answer you accepted seems to indicate that your question should be using the word "web site."  Logging in to a database implies direct database server access.  Can we change "database" to "web site" in this question and the title, so that the question matches the intention... as well as the answer?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Sure, it's a CRM we refer to as a database but yes it's technically a website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a field called "login_token" (make it a randomly generated string) and each time the user logs in, generate a new string and update the login_token field. Also store the login_token in the session. If a users session login_token value does not match that of the one in the database then kill the session.

Comment: Nice one, seems like a simple solution. Thanks